# Nanoid can't be used in react-native

Tags: react-native, nanoid

I don't know exactly what happened when I'm using the **nanoid** package in react native it's shown some kind of below error. I'm not sure about it.

I hope someone help from this community.

Thanks in advance.

Scenario: I just import to the nanoid package.

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
```

```
Error: React Native does not have a built-in secure random generator. If you don’t need unpredictable IDs use `nanoid/non-secure`. For secure IDs, import `react-native-get-random-values` before Nano ID.    
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\polyfills\error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError   
at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:204:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.43.19:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:203661:3 in global code
```

Comment: Have you tried importing `react-native-get-random-values` before?

Comment: Just now installed I'm gonna try it out and let you know

Comment: Now it was given new error :(

Comment: Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-get-random-values\getRandomBase64.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[0], "react-native").NativeModules.RNGetRandomValues.getRandomBase64')
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error

Comment: I was resolved this issue by using following functions. So I think in `nanoid` used `crypto` module so in `react-native` it doesn't exist. For that we need to use `nanoid/non-secure` module. Below I was also used `customAlphabet` method. Finally it works. :)

```
import { customAlphabet } from 'nanoid/non-secure';

const nanoid = customAlphabet('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 10);
```

Comment: sure I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Issue resolved**

I have resolved this issue by using the following functions.

So I think in the `nanoid` used `crypto` module so in `react-native` it doesn't exist.

For that, we need to use a `nanoid/non-secure` module. Below I have also used `customAlphabet` method.

Finally it works. :)

```
import { customAlphabet } from 'nanoid/non-secure'; 

const nanoid = customAlphabet('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 10);
```

Comment: The answer from @eckc is more accurate per the nanoid docks

Answer (score 10):

Add the `react-native-get-random-values` dependency and then import it before Nano ID:

```
import 'react-native-get-random-values'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
```

From the [Nano ID docs](https://github.com/ai/nanoid#react-native):

> React Native does not have built-in random generator. The following
> polyfill works for plain React Native and Expo starting with 39.x.
>
> Check react-native-get-random-values docs and install it. Import it
> before Nano ID.

Answer (score 1):

You could also import the following to your App.jsx/tsx or index file (if you don't mind the extra dependencies):

```
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
```

After this the following works where you need to use it:

```
import {nanoid} from 'nanoid';
```